# What does it mean when there is a term in parenthesis in an electronic configuration?

Tags: quantum-chemistry, spectroscopy, electronic-configuration

This may be a silly question, but I have not yet found an answer and I don't really know how to word my searches. I have been looking at the NIST Atomic Spectra Database (and also atomic physics papers) and I see configurations of excited states that have terms in parenthesis in them and I don't know what it means. For example, I might see a configuration for N II

2s2p<sup>2</sup>(<sup>4</sup>P)3p

and the term is listed as <sup>3</sup>S<sup>o</sup>.

What would the <sup>4</sup>P term in the middle of the configuration mean? When would you write a configuration like this?

Comment: At least to me it isn't really clear what you are asking. It would probably be beneficial to view this in context. Can you provide a citation for a paper or a link to the database.